# How to show that the relation $xRy$ if $\sin(x-y)=0$ is transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

"Logically" it seems transitive as if $x-y=k()$ and $y-z=k(\pi)$ then $x-z=k'(\pi)$ but how to put it into a good proof? also what would we be its equivalence classes since if it is transitive then it will be an equivalence relation (already proved it is reflexive and symmetric)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). And can you explain what does “$\sin(x-y)$ is transitive” *mean*?

Comment: Thank you, will take a look at it and improve.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos excuse my mistakes, I Improved the question it was lacking a lot

Comment: You should use different letters (i.e. don't use $k$ each time). This is because it is not necessarily the case that $x-y$, $y-z$ and $x-z$ would be the *same* multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth done, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\sin(x-y)=0$ and $\sin(y-z)=0$, then\begin{align}\sin(x-z)&=\sin\bigl((x-y)+(y-z)\bigr)\\&=\sin(x-y)\cos(y-z)+\cos(x-y)\sin(y-z)\\&=0.\end{align}So, yes, your relation is transitive.

Comment: Thank you, what about the equivalence class?

Comment: The equivalence class of $x$ is$$\{x+2k\pi\,|\,k\in\mathbb Z\}\cup\{\pi-x+2k\pi\,|\,k\in\mathbb Z\}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove $\sin(x-y) = 0 = \sin(y-z) = 0 \Rightarrow \sin(x-z) = 0$.

Now $\sin(x-y)=0 \Rightarrow \exists k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ x - y = k_1 \pi$. In the same way, $\exists k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ y - z = k_2 \pi$. So $x - z = x -y + y - z = (k_1 + k_2)\pi \Rightarrow \sin(x-z) = \sin((k_1 + k_2)\pi) = 0$ because $k_1 + k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So the equivalence classes are of the kind $x + \pi \mathbb{Z}$, with $x \in [0,\pi)$.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here $xRy$ if $\sin(x-y)=0$, i.e., if $x-y$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$. So, if $x-y$ and $y-z$ are integer multiples of $\pi$, then $x-z$ will be again an integer multiple of $pi$, implying that the relation is transitive.
The equivalence class corresponding to any $x$ will be $ {x+k \pi ; k is an integer}$.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it.